# Image Capture in Windows 8.1 C# Application

Tags: c#, windows, image, microsoft-metro, capture

I have a Desktop Based piece of Touch Screen Software.  As part of the process you capture a photo of the user to store later on.  The Application works perfectly fine in all versions of Windows other than Windows 8.1 on a Surface Pro 3 (seems to be machines with Metro on).

When it comes to Windows 8.1 the Application Captures the image with no issues.  When you then go back to the page to capture again it is unable to grab the camera to take another photo?

Using the Camera Capture in Windows 8.1 itself uses the camera with no issues again.  Restarting the Surface Pro allows the camera to work in the application again for one instance and then stops again.

I've tried scouring the web but not having much luck so far.  We're using the DirectShow lib

Any advice/ideas/help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Paul